# Coaching in Team Sealed events

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'll be doing my first [Team Sealed](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/li/208) event soon. I watched a video covering Grand Prix Providence and recall seeing one player sitting, playing his deck, while his two teammates coached heavily (*"Don't play that, play this instead"*, "*Play this first, then attack*", etc.). I had some doubts about how it works that weren't covered by the resources I found onlne.

- Is watching/coaching allowed by my teammates?
- Do all 3 players play matches at the same time?
- If coaching is allowed and everyone plays at the same time, do I have to be finished with my match in order to coach my teammate?

Any additional insight you'd like to share about this format is appreciated as well.

Comment: One additional thing I've seen at least once in video coverage (not sure if it happened at that Grand Prix or not) that probably won't happen to you is the video coverage folks actually holding one game while another finishes, so they can broadcast both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to help your teammates, the tournament is based on the skill of the team and decisions made therein. If you watch the worlds coverage you will see plenty of coaching there.

All 3 players play their matches at the same time. They can coach each other at any point, including mulligans.

Bear in mind though that you still have to play in a timely manner.